# Add scrollbar to displayed options from select tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a select tag that displays a few options like this :

```
<select class="form-control" name="selectedOption" [(ngModel)]='selectedOption'>
    <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf0dc;</i>
    <option value="">FirstOption</option>
    <option *ngFor="let row of options" [ngValue]="row">{{row}}</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is display only 6 options and add a scrollbar to scroll through the rest.
I tried adding size=6 to the select tag, but then all 6 options would display as a list, not in the dropdown.
What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: I doubt you can control it, it is browser specific.

Comment: You will need to build your own component.